# Converting comma separated string with key-value form into pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv

I would like to convert the following string into a pandas dataframe:

```
data = "key=iApFK, age=58, key=234das, age=64, key=89snkj, age=47"
```

The dataframe would look like this:

```
            key        age    
0           iApFK      58  
1           234das     64
2           89snkj     47
```

I tried doing it with pandas.read_csv and io.SringIO but I am confused regarding the extraction of the values and the delimiter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
pd.DataFrame(re.findall("key=(\w+), age=(\w+),?", data), columns=["key", "age"])
```

you can find fields with `re.findall`, then pass the result to pd.DataFrame along with the column names:

```py
In [32]: data
Out[32]: 'key=iApFK, age=58, key=234das, age=64, key=89snkj, age=47'

In [33]: re.findall("key=(\w+), age=(\w+),?", data)
Out[33]: [('iApFK', '58'), ('234das', '64'), ('89snkj', '47')]

In [34]: pd.DataFrame(re.findall("key=(\w+), age=(\w+),?", data), columns=["key", "age"])
Out[34]:
      key age
0   iApFK  58
1  234das  64
2  89snkj  47
```

Comment: genius! That did it!

Comment: That's clever ! Well done @MustafaAydın

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have reputation to comment so posting.
Mustafa Aydın answered correctly but for some easier cases

```
d = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='=', header=None, lineterminator=',')
```

will work.